# Resource referencing in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I am newbie to Android and playing with some Hello World codes.I observed that android put every resource i.e. image,string etc in `res` folder and we access it like `@drawable/icon` i.e `icon` image in drawable folder or like `R.layout.main` which means `main.xml` inside `layout` folder.

But while accessing strings we use `@string/string_name` but we dont specify its parent folder name i.e.`values`.Why syntax differs for `strings` ?
It may sound silly but it makes to think and put this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All resources of the same type in android is in a flat hierarchy.
You don't specify a directory name but instead the type of the resource.

Even if you split all strings between different files it will always be `@string/string_name` I'm afraid.

A good thing you can do to get some structure is to do something similar to this:

```
@string/error_network_io
@string/error_network_unknown_host
@string/message_save_successful
...
```

Comment: No problem, I think it's very good that you start asking these questions right away. Projects can easily get out of hand fast if you don't have a system for storing resources!

Comment: Yup. I was stuck at many points and StackOverflow always helped me out.